# NodeJS script to Update a JSON file where specific tags

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to write a NodeJS script

I have a data.json file with content like

```html
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "greeting",
      "patterns": [
        "Hi",
        "Hey",
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "goodbye",
      "patterns": [
        "Bye",
        "See you later",
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When we run the script, I want to update "!!!New Data!!!" to "patterns" in only tag "greeting" Like this

```html
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "greeting",
      "patterns": [
        "Hi",
        "Hey",
        "!!!New Data!!!"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "goodbye",
      "patterns": [
        "Bye",
        "See you later",
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please may you update the question with a [mcve] of _what you have already tried_.

Comment: can you please mark the answer, it'll help me lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let jsonObject = {
  intents: [
    {
      tag: "greeting",
      patterns: ["Hi", "Hey"],
    },
    {
      tag: "goodbye",
      patterns: ["Bye", "See you later"],
    },
  ],
};

jsonObject.intents = jsonObject.intents.map(({ tag, patterns }) => {
  return tag === "greeting"
    ? {
        tag,
        patterns: [...patterns, "!!!New Data!!!"],
      }
    : {
        tag,
        patterns,
      };
});

console.log(jsonObject);
```

Comment: @wp-dev Most Welcome, Keep learning, Keep Growing.!